# Unable to start minikube in windows using hyperv

Tags: windows, kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube

I installed minikube successfully on my windows machine and was using it. All of a sudden minikube start command failed to work one day, so I force-deleted .minikube directory and also removed minikube from Hyper-V Manager on Windows.

After this, I am unable to create/start minikube on my windows machine. I can see that a VM is created in Hyper-V manager but minikube is not starting with below error.

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv

* minikube v1.5.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.17763 Build 17763
* Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
* Using the running hyperv "minikube" VM ...
* Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
X minikube is unable to connect to the VM: dial tcp: address fe80::215:5dff:fe01:90b:22: too many colons in address
```

I came across this link which seems to be fixed long ago.
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/576

Can any one suggest other way to fix this ?

Comment: Could you please add the debug logs? `minikube start --v=7`. Also, you can try using Docker for Desktop, it includes Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks. Kubernetes works well with Docker for Desktop. minikube is a frustrating tool, always shows different errors in windows.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to append the port to the ip address, but is formatting incorrectly when the IP Address is IPv6 [Github Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/6110). Looks like there have been similar issues in the past and the solution has been to try again on a later version.

If you can force the VM to have an ipv4 address, that may work around this issue (hyper-V settings?)